# Kingston Datatraveler won't mount in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, usb-drive, 14.04

I try and try and try but ubuntu 14.04 is not recognizing my flash drive. It's a Kingston Datatraveler which has never caused me any problems before until now. Anybody know what to do?

Comment: Install Ubuntu 13.10 and be glad for it. Ubuntu 14.04 is still a work in progress.

Comment: One year later, I've just bought 4 DataTraveler Kingston G4 keys and none of them will mount in Ubuntu 14.04LTS.2. If anyone knows why, I'd love to see an answer to this question.

Comment: I also have the same issue, when using it in a 3.0 USB.

Comment: Same issue here as well, in 2019.

Comment: I found out with `dmesg | tail` that the device somehow gets disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. I tried the advice of pushing the USB in slowly. That didn't work.

What did work was pushing it in *very slowly* in a *timed manner*. Here is how:

I used `dmesg -wH` which keeps live updating `dmesg` in your terminal.

And *right* at the moment where Ubuntu said that it recognized it. I stopped pushing it in any further. Weirdly enough, this is as much a skill as learning how to use a small screwdriver or a semi-complex game controller combination in a video game.

My Kingston Datatraveler mounted. It did not mount by pushing it in slowly, but by pushing it in very slowly and immediately stopping when dmesgh said: "USB Mass Storage device detected"

Comment: wow! it really worked for me, thank you so much